# how do I check the data from AsyncStorage in native react?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-native, asyncstorage

how do I check the data from AsyncStorage in native react?
I have data in local storage like this

```
idKecamatan"3"
namaKecamatan"Jagakarsa, Jakarta Selatan, DKI Jakarta..."
```

I want to condition if the data exists then enter the first condition, if the data does not exist then enter the second condition, how do you condition it?

the assumption is like this

```
if(dataFromLocal !== null){
  return navigation.replace('MainApp')
else {
  return navigation.replace('CurrentLocation')
}
```

and this is a function of the condition

```
 const getAppToken = () => {
    const post = {
      user: 'dummy',
      secret: 'dummy'
    }

    api.post('/v1/mp/authenticate', post)
      .then(async (res) => {
        const { Data, Message } = res.data
        if (Message === 'SUCCESS') {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('app-token', Data.token)
          AsyncStorage.multiGet(['idKecamatan', 'namaKecamatan'], (err, stores) => {
            stores.map((result, i, store) => {
              let key = store[i][0]
              let val = store[i][1]
              console.log(key, val)
              if (key === null && val === null) {
                return navigation.navigate('CurrentLocation')
              } else {
               return navigation.replace('MainApp')
             }
            })
          })
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
navigation.navigate(dataKecamatan.idKecamatan ? 'MainApp' : 'CurrentLocation');
```

Comment: yes that's the previous example, but the data is not from the state, but from asyncstorage, the data from asyncstorage can I take, but how to condition it?

Comment: You can create a function like this:async retrieveData() {
  try {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('xxxx');
    navigation.navigate(data? 'MainApp' : 'CurrentLocation');
    
   } catch (error) {
     console.log("Error");
   }
}